# How to find the second whitespace of a string in php?

Tags: php

```
$string = "/kick <user> (time)"; //time is optional, user is required
if (!strpos($string, ' ')) {
    $firstSpace = strlen($string);
} else {
    $firstSpace = strpos($string, ' ');
}
```

I am designing an AJAX live support chatroom. Using `/command` i can do things such as ban users, show help etc, but I cannot kick users because of a problem.

To get the `<user>` I use this below formula to find the first whitespace.
How using php can I get `<time>` using strpos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) function:

```
$string = "/kick <user> (time)"; //because <user> is mandatory whereas (time) is optional
$pieces = explode(" ", $string);
echo $pieces[0]; // kick
echo $pieces[1]; // <user>
echo $pieces[2]; // (time)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the *offset* parameter:

```
strpos($string, ' ', strpos($string, ' '));
```

[Official documentation](https://www.php.net/strpos)